# How to view ParseException

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi I read the tutorials on basic parse features, etc. and I am using the ParseUser feature. From the tutorial this is shown :

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground("Jerry", "showmethemoney", new LogInCallback() {
  public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
    if (user != null) {
      // Hooray! The user is logged in.
    } else {
      // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened.
    }
  }
});
```

I was wondering how I could look at the ParseException to see what happened. For example, I want to inform the user that a bad username was entered, or a bad password.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [`ParseException.getCode()`](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseException.html#getCode()) method and the list of predefined error codes. You can also get a error message using [`ParseException.getMessage()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable.html?is-external=true#getMessage())

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think we may be talking about 2 different exceptions.  I am talking about the ParseException from the Parse Database which uses the ParseApi. Would what you said still work with mine?

Comment: yep, we are talking about the same exception. You can find `ParseException`'s documentation [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseException.html) (note that link points to `parse.com` site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need see the exception, can try show in the log or where you decide, in your code for te show in the log where Log.d(nameofalert,mensaje), only need see the logcat for the identify your exception

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground("Jerry", "showmethemoney", new LogInCallback() {
  public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {



if (user != null) {
Log.d("user not null",e.toString());
} else {
Log.d("error",e.toString());
      // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened.


  }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

a Pretty easy way to resolve this is to use

```
    e.getMessage();
    // this probably shows you appropriate message
    // or you can use
    e.getCode();
    // and match code with the integers given in Parse Doucmentation
    // for example. 
    // e.EMAIL_NOT_FOUND is code for when email is not found in registered users class
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your code in between try catch and in the catch block try to handle stuff that will go when user enter bad username or password

```
try{
}
catch(ParseException e)
{
// do stuff here
}
```

Comment: ya I was thinking that, how do I know specifically that a bad password was entered. Because a ParseException would be thrown if anything bad happened, such as bad username, password, etc. Do you know if there is like a UsernameParseException or something like that

Comment: You can check what caused the exception by comparing .getCode() to the list of exceptions here https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseException.html

Answer (score 1):

how about just doing `e.printStackTrace()`, that will print all the information that you need pertaining to the exception